# multi-thread application with queue, best approach to deliver each reply to the right caller?

Tags: python, multithreading, architecture, queue

Consider a multi-thread application, in which different pieces of code send commands to a background thread/service through a command `queue`, and consequently the service puts the replies in a reply `queue`. Is there a commonly accepted “strategy” for ensuring that a specific reply gets delivered to the rightful caller?

Coming to my specific case (a program in Python3), I was thinking about setting both the command and reply queues to `maxsize=1`, so that each caller can just put the command and wait for the reply (which will surely be its own), but this could potentially affect the performances of the application. Or else send a sort of unique code (a hash or similar) with the command, and have the background service include that same string in the reply, so that a caller can go through the replies, looking for its own reply and putting back the other replies in the queue. Honestly I don't like either of them. Is there something else that could be done?

I’m asking this because I’ve spent a fair amount of hours investigating online about threading, and reading through the official documentation, but I couldn’t make up my mind on this. I’m unsure which could be the right/best approach and most importantly I’d like to know if there is a mainstream approach to achieve this.

I don’t provide any code because the question deals with general application design.

Comment: These 'callers', do they ever have more than one request outstanding at a time, or do they queue one to the service and wait for its processing?

Comment: I mean, I don't know much Python, but in general, for synchronous requests, it's common for the 'callers' to queue up an object that can hold both the request, result, anything else that might be bound to the operation/s (eg. an error-message field:) and a suitable syncro object like and event or semaphore.  The caller queues up the request and waits on the synchro, the service performs the request and signals the synchro.

Comment: The callers can have more than one execution request at a time, but that's not an issue. My concern is that a reply to a command sent from a caller gets delivered to another caller, simply because the other calling thread happens to get the reply wrapper/object out of the reply queue at the wrong time, before the rightful recipient can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Associating a unique identifier with each request is basically the standard solution to this problem.

This is the solution employed by protocols from various eras, from DNS to HTTP/2.

You can build whatever abstractions you like on top of it.  Consider this semi-example using Twisted's `Deferred`:

```
def request(args):
    uid = next(id_generator)
    request_queue.put((uid, args))
    result = waiting[uid] = Deferred()
    return result

def process_responses():
    uid, response = response_queue.get()
    result = waiting.pop(uid)
    result.callback(response)

@inlineCallbacks
def foo_doer():
    foo = yield request(...)
    # foo is the response from the response queue.
```

The basic mechanism is nothing more than unique-id-tagged items in the two queues.  But the user isn't forced to track these UIDs.  Instead, they get an easy-to-use abstraction that just gives them the result they want.